# VBA VLookup Run-time error '13'

Tags: excel, vlookup, type-mismatch, vba

I am having an issue searching for the time value associated with a specific option in an Excel sheet. I have a for loop that goes through a collection called `myCol` and should use `VLookup` to find the associated time. Here is the code:

```
For Each colval In myCol
    Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colval, Worksheets("Options").Range("A2:B50"), 2, False)
Next colval
```

I have verified that the type of `colval` is String, but when I run the program I get the error:

> "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

Any ideas to help resolve this problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "run-time" error is a big clue, your `VLOOKUP` is probably returning an error in the same way it would on the worksheet

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: use `Application.Vlookup` and test for Error using `IfError` before handling the result?

Comment: I ended up solving this issue by changing the variable "Time" to "msg". Never what I would have guessed, but I realized that time is already defined as the current time. Thanks for everyone's help!